# Increasing difficulty of Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question

Undergraduate math student considering studying Complex Analysis this semester. My findings with Abstract Algebra was that it started quite easy (basic groups work), before getting increasingly difficult with the introduction of deeper structures and theorems.

Is Complex Analysis usually taught in a similar way? I'm finding the start of the class quite challenging, much moreso than Abstract Algebra, and am wondering if it will get substantially more difficult, or if there is simply a tough learning curve that I will adjust to.

(I have very little background in analysis, so I hope for the latter).

Comment: This is true generally speaking in mathematics. If you do not have a thorough background in and understanding of real analysis, DO NOT take complex analysis. You will be utterly lost.

Comment: This will depend very much on the specific course syllabus and the individual instructor.  With no information except the course title, it's impossible for us to tell what your course will be like.  You should talk to the instructor.

Answer (score 1):

I found that an undergraduate class is complex analysis did not depend on real analysis very much, and was a collection of engineering methods, very much useful for taking integrals, series and other applications on the engineer's level. An very good understanding of Calculus was critical but analysis much less so. (The graduate class was much harder.)

I would say if you have very strong Calculus background and are very comfortable with summations, continuity, convergence, regular and line integrals -- it should be ok.

**UPDATE**

May be easier to tell exactly if you post the syllabus or the covered topic list...

Comment: Maybe your first contact with complex function theory was"a collection of engineering methods" ; it is true that the purpose of many introductory lectures, typically "Complex function Theory for Signal Processing" (is it the case for you Thornside ?) is to give the student the aptitude to apply the Theorem of Residues on different standard contours. My own remembrance is the richness and the subtle flavor of the domain (Morera's, Picard's theorems among many others) with a difficulty to solve exercises because you need to incorporate rather often a certain dose of **geometry** into analysis...